# Save a txt file with double tab as separator

Tags: python, pandas

How can I save a table in txt file with double separator?

I can save a txt file with one tab as below:

```
df.to_csv("file1.txt", sep='\t', index=False)
```

```
Name    05:58   06:11   06:18
1234DCE -3.43   -3.427  -4.622
18DDD12 11.564  10.883  10.915
453FGH2A    0.351   0.176   0.0
8FF3EFA -0.72   0.888   -0.638
98ACD12 12.574  11.883  13.356
A2DA21  0.0 0.162   -0.162
ABC1234 -2.385  -2.348  -2.248
```

But need two tabs as sep.

Like below:

```
Name        05:58    06:11      06:18
1234DCE     -3.43   -3.427     -4.622
18DDD12    11.564   10.883     10.915
453FGH2A    0.351    0.176        0.0
8FF3EFA     -0.72    0.888     -0.638
98ACD12    12.574   11.883     13.356
A2DA21        0.0    0.162     -0.162
ABC1234    -2.385   -2.348     -2.248
```

Comment: Please be clear about the programming language in use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't pass a filename to [`to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html), Pandas will return a string. So you can add a second tab:

```
with open('file1.txt', 'w') as fp:
    content = df.to_csv(sep='\t', index=False)
    fp.write(content.replace('\t', '\t\t').strip())
```

However your data will not be well aligned (row 453FGH2A for example). Maybe you should use [`to_string`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html) instead:

```
df.to_string('file1.txt', col_space=16, justify='left',
             formatters={'Name': '{:<16}'.format}, index=False)
```

With `to_csv`:

```
Name        05:58       06:11       06:18
1234DCE     -3.43       -3.427      -4.622
18DDD12     11.564      10.883      10.915
453FGH2A        0.351       0.176       0.0
8FF3EFA     -0.72       0.888       -0.638
98ACD12     12.574      11.883      13.356
A2DA21      0.0     0.162       -0.162
ABC1234     -2.385      -2.348      -2.248
```

With `to_string`:

```
Name              05:58            06:11            06:18          
1234DCE          -3.430           -3.427           -4.622          
18DDD12          11.564           10.883           10.915          
453FGH2A          0.351            0.176            0.000          
8FF3EFA          -0.720            0.888           -0.638          
98ACD12          12.574           11.883           13.356          
A2DA21            0.000            0.162           -0.162          
ABC1234          -2.385           -2.348           -2.248
```

Comment: @ParvezAlam. I updated my answer. I just append `strip()` after `replace` to remove the extra row. You can also use `to_string`. Can you check my answer, please?

Answer (score 1):

The `to_csv` only accepts a single-character string as the delimiter. To achieve the desired output of using two tabs as a separator, you can modify the DataFrame before saving it to the CSV file.

```py
import pandas as pd
data = {
    'Code': ['U123_CA', 'C123_TR', 'I999_MU'],
    'Country': ['USA', 'Canada', 'India'],
    'Date': [2021, 2020, 2022]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_modified = df.copy()
df_modified = df_modified.astype(str)
df_modified = df_modified.apply(lambda x: '\t\t'.join(x), axis=1)
fout = r"D:/temp/output.csv"
df_modified.to_csv(fout, index=False, header=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

From [pandas.DataFrame.to_csv](https://pandas.DataFrame.to_csv) documentation, 'sep' is a string of one length, so not possible to pass 2 tabs. So can use a workaround as mentioned in below code.
Save the table as a CSV file and then format that CSV file to add 2 tabs.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'numbers': [1, 2, 3], 'colors': ['red', 'white', 'blue']}) # sample df
#print(df)
df.to_csv("file1.txt", sep=',', index=False) #save to CSV file.

#Format CSV file to add 2 tabs
with open("file1.txt", "r") as input:
     with open("file2.txt", "w") as output:
        for line in input:
            output.write(line.replace(",", "\t\t"))

print("2 tab file saved to file2.txt")
```

> output in 'file2.txt'

[image]

Comment: You can use `io.StringIO` to avoid creating an intermediate file.